# DBContext many-to-many relations - database first

Tags: .net, many-to-many, entity-framework-6

What is the requirement in the database to make `DBContext` with database first consider two tables as many-to-many and dropping the linking table from the autocreated entities?

I have in database

Table: Book

- id (Integer, PK)
- name (String)

Table: Author

- id (Integer, PK)
- name (String)

Table: BookAuthor

- id (Integer, PK)
- book_id (Integer, FK)
- author_id (Integer, FK)

And `Entity Framework 6.0` keeps creating the `BookAuthor` as en entity instead of creating `Author.Books` and `Book.Authors` navigation properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the 'id' PK column from the BookAuthor table and just use a composite primary key of book_id and author_id then regenerate the DbContext. *A primary key composed of the two columns (book_id, author_id) should be sufficient to uniquely identify entries into the linking, or associative, table.*

I believe this will help Entity Framework understand how to model this relationship in the Database Context.